Hello, I am using shared_preference in flutter, but when I release the app to testflight, shared_preference is not working
I am using shared_preference in flutter, but when I release the app to testflight, shared_preference is not working.
I thought it was permissions but I was surprised that permission is not needed when using UserDefault for iOS
